# Unable to change the default port of mongodb in CentOS server

Tags: mongodb, centos7

Basically I'm trying to change the default port of `mongodb` by changing the port in `mongod.conf` file . Then I'm starting the db by `mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log` command . The db is being started in the background but the problem is it's still running on the port `27017`.

**mongod.conf:**

```
net:
  port: 15031
  bindIp: 192.168.1.7
```

Comment: I really went into the centOS and made the exchange for the file and it did not result in very strange success.

Comment: I'm checking the documentation.

Comment: So it's on another port, but if you give a mongo the shell will not be able to connect, but if you indicate the new port to the mongo shell it connects to the new port. I auditioned for port 28017 and it worked.

Comment: Change the port in the file and then reboot the service. 
`mongo 127.0.0.1:28017` And then to see if the mongo is running on the correct door.

Comment: @AMS thanks for your suggestion sir but unfortunately it's not working

Comment: Using the --port parameter?

Comment: @Marco thank a lot for your answer sir it solved my issue by the way could you please add an answer so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the parament `mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf` to specify the configuration file.

```
net:
  port: 15031
```

Configuration file is written in **YAML** 
You have to use **SPACE** characters instead of TAB characters for indentation.

Or pass the --port argument when you start mongod

```
mongod  --port 15031
```

Comment: It does not work, in an attempt to answer his doubts, I logged in to the centOS of digitalocean and did the port change through the file, the mongo does not change the port for some unknown reason that I'm investigating, but changing only the file does not result in success.